# NSArray append in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray

I have this array:

```
    var menuTableArray: NSArray = [["image": "", "title": "test"],
                                   ["image": "", "title", "test"]]
```

how to append new data in this array?

Comment: `var anArray:[String] = ["foo"]; anArray.append("bar")` It might be better to avoid `NSArray` and use `Array` which is a swift class. Declaring it as a `var` allows you to append elements.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using NSArray here? If you don't have a specific reason to use NSArray you should just use Swifts Array like

```
var menuTableArray: [[String: String]] = [["image": "", "title": "test"],
                               ["image": "", "title", "test"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append to an `NSArray` as it is **immutable**, even if you declare it as `var`. Use `NSMutableArray` instead.

```
var menuTableArray: NSMutableArray = [["image": "", "title": "test"],
                                      ["image": "", "title": "test"]]
menuTableArray.addObject(["image":"an image", "title": "test2"])
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use `var fooBar:Array[String]` instead of using `NSMutableArray` unless there is a specific reason to use `NS` classes.

Comment: Yes that is a fair point.